# Can't bind to second view

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat to display the data I received from a service in the view. Each item has a href attribute that will direct the user to location path for the second view and also a ng-click attribute that will pass the clicked item as a parameter back to the controller i.e.

View

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
  <td><a ng-href="#/view2" ng-click="select(item)">{{item.name}}</a></td>
  <td>{{item.desc}}</td>
</tr>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('myApp')
      .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, dataService) {

        dataService.getData().then(function (data) {
          $scope.items = data;
        });

        $scope.select = function (item) {
          $scope.selectedItem = item;
        }
    });
```

View2

```
<div>
  {{selectedItem.name}}
  {{selectedItem.desc}}
</div>
```

I'm receiving the item object okay within the function, but why am I unable to bind $selectedItem into View2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $rootScope instead:

```
    $scope.select = function (item) {
      $rootScope.selectedItem = item;
    }
```